# PHP/JQuery/AJAX, few teething problems

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

Morning/Afternoon guys.

Writing some JQuery AJAX shizz and getting a bit stuck. I've got the actual proccess of calling the php file done perfectly, its just trying to get the html on the page to change in a way I want it to. I want to get rid of the a with the id of the one used in the ajax call etc, and replace it with the html passed from the PHP file. Code is as follows...

```
$(".save_places").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "{/literal}{$sRootPath}{literal}system/ajax/fan_bus.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: ({id : this.getAttribute('id')}),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){
      $(this).before(msg);
      $(this).empty();
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

And the HTML is pretty simple;

```
<p class="links">
  <a href="#" class="save_places" id="bus_{$businesses.results[bus].id}_{$sMemberDetails.id}"><img src="{$sThemePath}images/save_places.png" alt="Save to My Places" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="{$sThemePath}images/send_friend.png" alt="Send to a Friend" /></a>
</p>
```

All the stuff in the success function is experimental mashing of code, any help please?

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're after is [`.replaceWith()`,](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) like this:

```
$(this).replaceWith(msg);
```

This replaces the `<a></a>` with the content coming back in `msg`.

Also, if you're sure the elements have IDs, you can just do this:

```
data: {id : this.id},
```

Comment: Nick, the refined data: stuff works a treat, much neater, thanks! Although the replaceWith doesn't seem to be working, there's no change to the <a> tag, and also no javascript errors :/ When using $(this), it wouldn't matter that theres loads of other class="save_places" would it?

Comment: @thebluefox - I haven't fully woken up yet :) give this a try for your success `success: $.proxy(function(msg){ $(this).replaceWith(msg); }, this)`

Comment: Boom there we go! Absolutely spot on mate, much appreciated. And come on! I've been up 6 hours already!

Answer (score 1):

```
linksPara.replaceChild(newElements, oldAtag);
```